# Xcode: Cannot preview in this file; Timed out waiting for connection to DTServiceHub after 15.0 seconds

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to run my home screen widget on Xcode and I receive the following error:

```
Xcode: Cannot preview in this file; Timed out waiting for connection to DTServiceHub after 15.0 seconds
```

I tried reinstalling Xcode, running on different devices (including old ones) but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!